# Can Vitamin C and E supplements cure or manage Preeclampsia resulting from oxidative stress?

Tags: nutrition, obstetrics, hypertension, prenatal-vitamins

According to Judith E. Brown's fifth edition of the "Nutrition Through Life Cycle" textbook,

"Oxidative stress and lack of anitoxidant defences appear to play key roles in the development of Preeclampsia in pregnant women".

At that, can antioxidants like Vitamin C(fruits or supplements) and Vitamin E be an effective cure to eliminate or manage Preeclampsia in the sense of reducing oxidative stress and reducing risk of preeclampsia?

Comment: Can you cite a source for your first sentence?

Comment: @CareyGregory Its from a Textbook written by, Judith E. Brown "Nutrition Through the Life Cycle". From the fifth Chapter, "Nutrition During Pregnancy". I wanted to cite the sentence in the body at first, but I couldn't remember how to arrange and put it in order as suggested by APA . And the search engines were of little help.

Comment: @CareyGregory Could you help with an answer?

Comment: Not an area of expertise for me but someone else may chime in. What we need you to do is edit your question and add the reference you cited above. Format is unimportant. We don't require citations to follow any particular style guide. To edit, just click the edit link directly under the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There have been several trials testing this and they have not shown benefit.

One example of the conclusion from such a trial:

> Supplementation with vitamins C and E during pregnancy does not reduce the risk
>   of preeclampsia in nulliparous women, the risk of intrauterine growth restriction, or
>   the risk of death or other serious outcomes in their infants.

Rumbold, A. R., Crowther, C. A., Haslam, R. R., Dekker, G. A., & Robinson, J. S. (2006). Vitamins C and E and the risks of preeclampsia and perinatal complications. New England Journal of Medicine, 354(17), 1796-1806.

And a summary of 15 trials from the WHO, with a strong "not recommended" guidance:

> Evidence related to the differential effects of
>   antioxidants in the prevention of pre-eclampsia
>   and its complications was extracted from a
>   Cochrane systematic review of 15 RCTs involving
>   a total of 22 359 women (14). Most of the trials
>   had compared one or more vitamins, particularly
>   combined vitamins C and E regimens, with
>   placebo. When antioxidants were compared with
>   placebo, there were no statistically significant
>   differences in the critical (and proxy) maternal
>   outcomes of pre-eclampsia
>
> No statistical
>   differences were observed for any of the infantrelated critical (and proxy) outcomes addressed
>   in the trials
>
> Individual or combined vitamin C and vitamin
>   E supplementation during pregnancy is not
>   recommended to prevent the development of
>   pre-eclampsia and its complications.
>   •    (High-quality evidence.
>   Strong recommendation.)

World Health Organization. (2011). WHO recommendations for prevention and treatment of pre-eclampsia and eclampsia.